# javascript assignment inside event handling anonymous method

Tags: javascript, events, anonymous

i tried to make assignment to local variable in function like below:

```
    getMousePosition()
    {
      let mousePos = [];
      canvas.mousemove(function(e) { mousePos = [e.clientX, e.clientY]; });

      if(mousePos[0] != undefined)
      console.log(mousePos[0] + " " + mousePos[1]);
    }
```

and my mousePos variable have undefined value all the time. Why something like that is a problem?

Comment: `onmousemove`,.

Comment: @Keith can you be more specific? Is it any different? In JQUERY `mousemove` should work, isn't it?